# React telling me I am using minified in dev ...

Tags: reactjs

So this is my task:

```
gulp.task('prod', function() {
  browserify({entries: [
    'resources/assets/js/app.js'
  ]})
  .transform("babelify")
  .transform(envify({
     NODE_ENV: 'production'
  }))
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('all.js'))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .on('error', gutil.log)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'));
});
```

yet the console still sais:

```
all.js:30 Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster. See [url here that stack doesn't like] for more details.
```

So I am confused. Whats the deal?

Comment: I konw it may be strange, but can you try to replace `NODE_ENV: 'production'` to `NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running build process, set NODE_ENV like this (linux):

```
NODE_ENV=production gulp build
```

Or (Windows)

```
SET NODE_ENV=production
gulp build
```

If you added build script to your package.json - you can run npm:

```
npm run --production build
```

Or you can try to modify your scrips:

```
  ...
  .transform(envify({
     'process.env.NODE_ENV': 'production'
  }))
  ...
```

But this depends on what version of envify you are using

Comment: If you know about objects in javascript you'll know that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is an illegal key due to the `.`

Comment: @TheWebs that is incorrect. Object property names may indeed contain `.` characters (as well as most other Unicode characters provided literally or by an escape sequence). In Evgeniy's example, the key is provided as a string, so the `.` characters will be interpreted as just that - characters in a string. In fact, ALL JS object property/key names are coerced to strings behind the scenes.

Comment: ...except Symbols, which are obviously not coerced into strings (this is beside the point for the purposes of this question, but I want to clarify this for future readers)

Comment: This is like a year old, none of this applies any more

Answer (score 0):

You should use minified react version for production bundles. Minifying by yourself react code is not a solution, because there are many conditions like: `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'` in it.

You can take a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#development-vs.-production-builds):

> We provide two versions of React: an uncompressed version for development and a minified version for production. The development version includes extra warnings about common mistakes, whereas the production version includes extra performance optimizations and strips all error messages.

So you should use `react.min.js` from `/node_modules/react/dist` instead of `/node_modules/react/lib/React` for production bundles.

Comment: I do not know of any way to do a require statement on a minified version of react ... I just use `import React from 'react'`

Comment: This is incorrect. Performing minification yourself is absolutely a solution. In fact, it is generally recognized as the preferred method. The prepackaged standalone scripts contain all dependencies (libraries, helpers, shims/polyfills, etc.) embedded, so you lose any benefits of shared dependency deduplication amongst your other libraries, as well as your control over explicit dependency version declaration. All major bundlers/build systems have ways of either exporting or spoofing environment variables for the conditional checks that you mention.